# bundle error missing file only in sudo

Tags: ruby, bundle

I don't understand the following error :

If I run `sudo bundle` on my rails app folder, it runs fine. Without the sudo however, I get a permission denied :

```sh
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86-linux/2.0.0/bcrypt-3.1.9 (Errno::EACCES)
   from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
   ....
```

Okay, but I checked the said folder `[...]/x86-linux/2.0.0/`, and the folder `/bcrypt-3.1.9` doesn't even exist ! (However I do have a folder `bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2`)

What's wrong ? How can I fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failing command is `mkdir`, which is trying to *create* that directory. So that's why the directory doesn't exist.

If you are using linux or osx, you can use the `chmod` command to change the permissions for that directory, for example

```
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86-linux/2.0.0
```

Unfortunately there are too many potential things to list here which would cause filesystem permissions errors like the one you are getting. I would recommend posting the output of `ls -l /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86-linux/2.0.0` if you still can't fix it.

Comment: That folder currently has permission 775 with user/grp root/rvm. I only have a couple gem folders there : atomic, bcrypt, json, mysql2, pg, sqlite, therubyracer.

Comment: @CyrilDD If the user/group is root/rvm, then obviously you either have to run `bundle` as root (with sudo) or as someone in the rvm group.

Comment: Yeah so I just added the username of my rails app folder to the rvm group. Is this the right way to go ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the username of my rails app folder"? Folders don't have usernames. You need to add the username of whoever is running `bundle` to the rvm group (presumably this would be your username).

Comment: Haha yes sorry I meant the name of the owner of the rails folder. That is exactly what you said (I'm using Capistrano, and executing bundle with a specific user).
I was just asking if this was the best practice.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how unix-style permissions work, but I'm guessing that the owner of the rails folder has nothing to do with it. It is probably best practice to solve the problem by adding yourself to the rvm group.